# Stopping css button from changing postion on the click

Tags: css

I am positioning button with CSS but whenever i click the button it keeps on moving to the top and back to it's position.
How can i stop it from happening?

```css
.myButton {
 background-color:#4b4d4c;
 border:1px solid #ffffff;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:17px;
 padding:11px 76px;
 text-decoration:none;
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;

    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);

}
.myButton:hover {
 background-color:#373838;
}
.myButton:active {

 top:1px;
}
```

```html
            <div>
              <br>
            </div>
            <div>
               <br>
            </div>
            <div>
              <br>
            </div>
            <div>
            <br>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="myButton">More ></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is `positioned` as `absolute`, and every-time when you `click` that it goes to `top:1px` from it's assigned or translated position instead use negative value of `margin-top`.

```
.myButton:active {
  /*top: 1px;*/ /*Remove this*/
  margin-top:-1px;
}
```

> position:absolute - The element is removed from the normal document
>   flow; no space is created for the element in the page layout. Instead,
>   it is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any;
>   otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its
>   final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and
>   left.

```css
.myButton {
  background-color: #4b4d4c;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 11px 76px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.myButton:hover {
  background-color: #373838;
}

.myButton:active {
  /*top: 1px;Remove this*/
  margin-top:-1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<a href="#" class="myButton">More ></a>
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. That is quite funny.

Comment: @Mac Adding margin-top negative value could help you here, if you are trying to pull button on every click.

Comment: I did not really understood what it does. it was there by mistake. Removing top: 1px; did it for me. Thanks and sorry for such mistake but i read your answer and it might be useful what i learned from it.

Comment: I actually used it but it looks like an animation. Pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use `margin-top` instead of `top`:

```
.myButton:active {
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```css
.myButton {
  background-color: #4b4d4c;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 11px 76px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.myButton:hover {
  background-color: #373838;
}

.myButton:active {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <br>
</div>
<a href="#" class="myButton">More ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `top:1px;` from

`.myButton:active {
  top:1px;
}`

When you click on button and it's state is `active` it moves your button to top of the page.. Think what you want to do with your button when it's active.
If you want it just to move slightly by 1px then you should make it's position to `absolute`.